# Postgresql Update Polygon Geometry using ST_removePoint

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I Have a table named `geofences` which stores geometry of Polygon type in column named `geometry`. I to update the Polygon  by removing only one point from the exsisting geometry. For this I Have used the query:

```
 UPDATE gfe_geofences
   SET geometry = ST_RemovePoint(geometry, ST_NPoints(ST_GeomFromText(
                     'POINT(23.1446787840563 96.002746420167)', 0) ) - 1)
   WHERE is_active = true
     AND ST_IsClosed(the_geom) = true;
```

But it gives me the error:

> ERROR:  lwline_deserialize: attempt to deserialize a line which is
>   really a Invalid type

Can you please help me in updating the geometry.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What version of PostGIS? Is `geometry` a LineString type? What is `the_geom`, or is that a typo for `geometry` (or vice versa)?

Comment: PostGIS 9.1  , No geometry is of Polygon type , For LineString ST_Remove is working file the_geom is a column (Ignore this condition AND ST_IsClosed(the_geom) = true;)

Answer (score 1):

ST_RemovePoint will only work with linestrings ( see http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_RemovePoint.html.  What I would do, use ST_Boundary to get the boundary of your polygon, call ST_RemovePoint on that, then use ST_MakePolygon to construct a new polygon.